# Calculating Relative Recall

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval, precision-recall

When calculating relative recall using TREC and 'K' pooling, does the total relevant documents reflect relevant documents from all participating systems per query or is it all the queries?

And does this approach not invalidate recall calculations, say I have the 50 top documents between two systems but collectively there are 75 relevant documents, then irrespective of how good either system is they will never be able to reach 100% recall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When calculating relative recall using TREC and 'K' pooling, does the total relevant documents reflect relevant documents from all participating systems per query or is it all the queries?

The set of relevant documents comprises documents that are judged relevant by human accessors, who are asked to look at the **union** of top-100 documents retrieved by each participating system. Note the stress on the word **union**, which indicates that the accessors are not shown this set in any particular order. So, this pool is indeed a set (and not an ordered set).

The set of relevant documents is different for each query. So you might imagine if *R* represents relevant set of documents, it has an argument *q* (the query). So, in effect you have *R(q)* and not just *R*.

> And does this approach not invalidate recall calculations, say I have the 50 top documents between two systems but collectively there are 75 relevant documents, then irrespective of how good either system is they will never be able to reach 100% recall?

They can, in principle, achieve 100% recall if they retrieve at least 75 documents each. Obviously, if you're allowed to retrieve 10 documents and there are a total of 20 relevant documents, tha max. recall you can achieve is only *50%*.